# Forwardticks in example command in `man emerge`: local misconfiguration or typo?

Tags: bash, man, emerge

In [Manpage of EMERGE](http://dev.gentoo.org/~zmedico/portage/doc/man/emerge.1.html) it is stated: *To find files that need to be updated in /etc, type find /etc -iname ´._cfg????_*´*  Taking a closer look at it (copy-pasted from terminal -- not from the online version of the manual): `find /etc -iname ´._cfg????_*´`.

Using exactly this command won't work because the string in question is inside forward-ticks `´...´` 
and not inside single quotes, like find `/etc -iname '._cfg????_*'` which works as expected.

Is this a local misconfiguration or a typographical error in the Manpage (which means that I should direct this question to https://bugs.gentoo.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such unicode characters are most likely a result of some non-standard program generating the manual output and mangling normal quotes to something that looks nicer when printed out, but what is incorrect if you copy-and-paste it. Alternatively I have seen this happen with people writing programs/documentation on Apple systems.

I had a similar problem with the manual for `web2py`. In that PDF file were some quotes that I just copy-and-paste into my apache config, only to find out much later that a pattern was never matched because these were not normal quotes. The result was that static files were not served by Apache, but by the web2py code itself (which was slower), and it just took a long time to notice because the pages took some time to be generated anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Is `less` in the (virtual) terminal a *non-standard program*? I use man version 2.6.5 in bash version 4.2.45(1)-release and let the output go through less for which I have the following in `.bashrc`: `export LESS='-i -w  -z-4 -g -e -M -X -F -R -P%t?f%f \
:stdin .?pb%pb\%:?lbLine %lb:?bbByte %bb:-...'`.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris the short version of what Anthon is telling you is: it's a bug in the manpage. He's giving some things that the manpage's author may have done that may be reason for the bug.

Comment: For your interest, I've reported this: https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=509540